# Signal on X11 Logout

Tags: linux, x11, logout

I am writing an application that will occasionally save data. The Problem is now, when a user logs out of X11 and my application did not yet save the changes, is there a way to detect the logout and write the changes to disk? I tried inmplementing a signal handler for `SIGHUP` and `SIGQUIT` without success. Is there a signal that gets emitted or is there a way to lsiten for a logout?

Comment: What is your application? What toolkit are you using?

Comment: Consider upgrading to GTK3.

Comment: Then you are stuck, or you need many months (or years) of coding to implement that. Porting your code to GTK3 should be easier.

Comment: Why can't you use GTK3? That should go into your question!

Comment: In practice, this question *is bound* to a toolkit. Otherwise, you'll need to implement all of EWMH yourself (and that will take many years). So changing your toolkit could be much more practical. Of course you could reimplement an EWMH compliant toolkit above raw X11, but that means dozens of years of work. Can you afford that? Explain what is your application doing.

Comment: No signal is emitted on X11 logout. But I leave the drama to you. Feel free to spend 6 months trying to implement EWMH, and tell us, six months later, how it was easy.

Comment: If you think that SIGTERM is emitted, just install a signal handler for it and handle it. But read  [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). I am pretty sure that `SIGTERM` is not emitted in that case. But you need to discover it too. Remember that X11 can be a remote protocol: the X11 server, and the window manager, could run on a distant machine (not on the same machine as your application). Try with `ssh -X`

Comment: If you are so sure that `SIGTERM` is emitted, why don't you try to handle it?

Comment: For other readers. A possible reason to get stuck to GTK2 is [lablgtk](http://lablgtk.forge.ocamlcore.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Read [ICCCM](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/specs/ICCCM/icccm.html) and [EWMH](https://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html) (both are quite large specifications that you should read carefully).

In practice, your X11 application is likely to use some existing GUI toolkit like e.g. [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [GTK](http://gtk.org/) (be sure to use at least GTK3). Then that toolkit should have support related to sessions.

For Qt: look into [QSessionManager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsessionmanager.html#details).

For GTK: see [GtkApplication](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html)

(if you are stuck with GTK2 - e.g. with [lablgtk](http://lablgtk.forge.ocamlcore.org/) -, you'll spend months or one or two years of efforts to implement EWMH sessions in your code; porting it to GTK3 -or even to Qt5- should be wiser and might be less work) Since GTK (both GTK2 and GTK3) is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), you could study the source code (and perhaps be inspired by it, or adapt it to your needs, and/or make an educated guess of the amount of efforts to rewrite it).

Remember that [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) is a network protocol, and the server and the client (and the window manager) could run on *different* machines (e.g. thru `ssh -X`). Sending `SIGTERM` through the network has no sense (and that could explain why EWMH don't mention it).

A workaround might perhaps be to save the state periodically (e.g. every two minutes; then only two minutes of work is lost).

Answer (score 0):

Basile's recommendation of looking at your toolkit's relevant classes ([QSessionManager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsessionmanager.html) and [GtkApplication](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html)) is good. I'm thankful he posted that because it helped me find the specific stuff I was looking for.

But if it's as you say, and your toolkit doesn't have built-in session management support, the relevant specification is not EWMH, but rather [XSMP](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libSM/xsmp.html). There's a small amount of additional information included in [ICCCM](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/specs/ICCCM/icccm.html) that you should also watch out for.

This is far from being a couple years of work. The relevant client-side portions of the session manager protocol should only take a few hours, maybe a couple days if you're unfamiliar with integrating low-level X11 protocols into an existing application stack.

Comment: Ive already implemented that already. I thought from the beginning that Basile is overdramatising this immensly. It was not that much of work (I think I got it down in about 30 Minutes of reading and 45 minutes of implementing).

Comment: I kinda assumed as much. :) I just wanted to follow up for other people who find this question, because I needed an answer myself.